# Sinatra app with Grape API

Tags: apache, angularjs, sinatra, ruby-grape

I'm running a Sinatra App along with Grape. 
I've seen other postings on SO in about how to run the two together or any other Rack compliant solutions, though my quandary is a bit different.

I would need to preface that most solutions I've noticed to run the two together show to have Grape mounted on some route, though that's not what I'm doing.
I simply: `Rack::Cascade.new[SinatraApp,GrapeAPI]` 
Everything is working as it should, except when I deployed out to Apache I noticed that stderr logs out the calls to the api with a 404, even though it is properly returning my JSON.

I am setting mime types out with `default_format :json` on my Grape routes. Is that just not happening? I do have angular making the calls to Grape via the $http service and I I confirm in dev tools that I am receiving `application/json` types.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. Your API's JSON responses are making it all the way back to the client, correct? If you're asking why the 404 errors are appearing in the logs, is it possible they are being generated by Sinatra and used to trigger [Rack::Cascade](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Cascade.html) to delegate the request to your Grape API?

Comment: That's pretty wonky... Suppose a misuse of Cascade on my behalf? I'll just mount on /api or something. I didn't expect it would behave that way.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue? I'm running into the exact problem